# @Test(expected = Exception.class) or Assertions.assertThrows(...) or assertThatThrownBy(..) which one is recommended?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am using JUnit 4.12

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
    <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I wanted to know which one is most recommended to use
`@Test(expected = Exception.class)` or `Assertions.assertThrows(...)`

Comment: The main advantage of assertions (e.g. assertj's `assertThatThrownBy`)  is that you can further assert certain properties of the exception, e.g. that the message contains certain words etc. I found that helpful for making sure I did not forget any parameter-checks, as I always mention which parameter was invalid in `NullPointerException`s and `IllegalArgumentException`s intentionally thrown during validation of a methods preconditions.

Comment: thoughts go out to the developers such as myself having migrating 1000's of `@Test(expected=...)` to `Assertion.assertThrows` blocks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With JUnit 4.12 there are several ways to test code for expected exceptions.

### try-catch

We can simply use Java's try-catch.

```
@Test
public void testInvalidData() {
    prepareTestData();

    try {
        userService.fetchUser(1234);
        Assert.fail("IllegalArgumentException not thrown");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException expected) {
    }
}
```

Whenever we use this approach, we have to make sure to call `Assert.fail(...)` in case the expected exception was not thrown.

### Annotation Attribute

As you already mentioned, the `@Test` has an attribute to declare the expected exception.

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testInvalidData() {
    prepareTestData();

    // should throw IllegalArgumentException
    userService.fetchUser(1234);
}
```

The test is green if the test method throws the exception. The test is red if the test method throws no exception or a different exception.

This has one big disadvantage: We can't figure out which instruction throws the IllegalArgumentException. If `prepareTestData();` throws the exception, the test is still green.

### Rule ExpectedException

JUnit 4 contains the built-in rule ExpectedException. (please remember that JUnit 5 uses extensions instead of rules)

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testInvalidData() {
    prepareTestData();

    thrown.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    userService.fetchUser(1234);
}
```

This approach is similar to try-catch and `@Test(expected = ...)`, but we can control from which point the exception is expected.

### assertThrows

AssertJ and JUnit 5 provide methods to assert that a specific code block throws a specific exception.

```
@Test
public void testInvalidData() {
    prepareTestData();

    Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
        userService.fetchUser(1234);
    });
}
```

`Assertions.assertThrows` also returns the exception object to execute further asserts, e.g. to assert the message.

### Summary

I try to use `assertThrows` as often as possible because the test code gets both readable and flexible. But all the other mentioned approaches are also valid if correctly used.

Answer (score 0):

expectedExceptions comes from Test class family, assertThrows comes from Assert class family. Both will fail if the expected exception does not throw from the method in test.

Doc for expectedExceptions:

```
/**
 * The list of exceptions that a test method is expected to throw.  If no
 * exception or a different than one on this list is thrown, this test will be
 * marked a failure.
 */
public Class[] expectedExceptions() default {};
```

Doc for assertThrows

```
/**
 * Asserts that {@code runnable} throws an exception when invoked. If it does not, an
 * {@link AssertionError} is thrown.
 *
 * @param runnable A function that is expected to throw an exception when invoked
 * @since 6.9.5
 */
```

Both of them translates to:

```
try {
        ....
} catch (SomeException e) {

}
```

expectedExceptions can take more than one Exception instances. assertThrows() can be used as a replacement for expectedException though (it is latest). It makes more sense when you have to continue after assertThrows.